# Is it possible that functional quick-sort runs faster than imperative quick-sort?

Tags: sorting, functional-programming, kotlin, quicksort

I am trying to understand functional programming, and while the code looks beautiful, I was worried that there will be a performance hit as compared to an imperative implementation.

However, I am completely surprised to see that the functional implementation is much much faster than my imperative implementation (which looks ugly).

Now, I am sure that there is some mistake in my imperative implementation, yet, I am not sure what that mistake is..

Some benchmarks:
functional on a size of 35 elements:
152954779 ns

Imperative on 35:
198337749325 ns

This worsens even if I add 10 elements to the list

Code is in kotlin:

Imperative:

```
fun quickSort(numbers: IntArray, l: Int, r: Int): IntArray {
if (l >= r)
    return numbers

fun swap(m: Int, n: Int) {
    val temp = numbers[m]
    numbers[m] = numbers[n]
    numbers[n] = temp
}

var i = l + 1
var j = l + 1
val pivot = numbers[l]
while (j < r) {
    if (numbers[j] < pivot) {
        if (numbers[i] > pivot) {
            swap(i, j)
        }
        i++
    }
    j++
}
swap(l, i - 1)
quickSort(numbers, 0, i - 1)
quickSort(numbers, i, r)
return numbers
}
```

I am sure I can refactor this and improve it, yet, that is not my goal right now.

Imperative 2:

```
fun partitionTest(arr: IntArray, left: Int, right: Int): Int {

var i = left
var j = right
var tmp: Int

val pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2]

while (i <= j) {
    while (arr[i] < pivot)
        i++
    while (arr[j] > pivot)
        j--
    if (i <= j) {
        tmp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[j]
        arr[j] = tmp
        i++
        j--
    }
}
return i
}


fun quickSortTest(arr: IntArray, left: Int, right: Int) {

val index = partitionTest(arr, left, right)

if (left < index - 1)

    quickSort(arr, left, index - 1)

if (index < right)

    quickSort(arr, index, right)

}
```

Functional:

```
fun functionalQuickSort(numbers: IntArray): IntArray {
return when {
    numbers.size <= 1 -> numbers
    else -> {
        val pivotIndex = 0
        functionalQuickSort(numbers.filter { it < numbers[pivotIndex] }.toIntArray()) + numbers[pivotIndex] + functionalQuickSort(
            numbers.filter { it > numbers[pivotIndex] }.toIntArray()
        )
    }
  }
}
```

Main:

```
val numbers = Random().ints(10).toArray()
var start = System.nanoTime()
functionalQuickSort(numbers).also { println(it.contentToString()) }
var end = System.nanoTime()
println("Took ${end - start}")


start = System.nanoTime()
quickSort(numbers,0,numbers.size).also { println(it.contentToString()) }
end = System.nanoTime()
println("Took ${end - start}")
```

Comment: You will tell us, the imperative sort of 35 elements needs 198 seconds?

Comment: When you pass `numbers` to `quickSort` they seem to be already sorted.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: We don't see complete code, but it appears to be likely. if so, wouldn't `quickSort` then be a (almost) no-op (just loop once and don't do anything)?

Comment: This isn't exactly imperative programming, is it? There are function declarations that calls themselves recursively, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Learn a thing or two about [micro-benchmarks on the JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html) before starting to draw any conclusions.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, no, numbers isn't already sorted, since functionalQuickSort does not sort in place, it returns a new array.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, thanks for sharing the link, I will read through it!

Comment: I think your imperative QuickSort is broken.

Comment: Well, there is definitely an issue. I even copied a solution online (and it seems to be following the same intuition that I follow), even that takes a long time over 30 elements.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - "... be a no-op" No, the `val pivot = numbers[l]` says this is the quicksort variation that will be O(n^2) for already sorted.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik This article that you provided is excellent, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html.

Thank you

Comment: @HenkHolterman you're absolutely right. This is bad! Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to find it, but there's a bug in your recursive call:

```
  quickSort(numbers, 0, i - 1)
```

This should be:

```
  quickSort(numbers, l, i - 1)
                     ^
```

As a small optimization, you can also return early on segments of length 1 (in addition to length 0):

```
  if (l + 1 >= r)
    return numbers
```

There seem to be a few more issues that I haven't looked into in detail. The nested `if` in your `while` loop looks dodgy to me; I think the inner `if` could be removed:

```
  while (j < r) {
    if (numbers[j] < pivot) {
      swap(i, j)
      i++
    }
    j++
  }
```

Think carefully about what your invariants are and whether each statement maintains them.

With these adjustments, the imperative version runs about 10 times faster on 100000 elements.

Also consider what happens if two elements are equal, which is unlikely with such a small array but will happen for arrays of 100000 elements (birthday paradox). You will find that your functional implementation is broken in this case.

---

On the subject of benchmarking:

- Make sure that your input is big enough to get data instead of noise. A running time of more than a second is good.
- Don't include the generation of input data.
- Definitely don't include the printing of output. I/O is relatively slow.

Comment: Accepted your answer since it helped me catch my bug! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I used a known-good imperative QuickSort algorithm instead of yours which looks quite broken to me. My partitioning code is structurally different than yours because it uses C.A.R. Hoare's original scheme, while yours seems to be using the Lomuto scheme (popular for its simplicity, but not its efficiency).

I also wrote the code that takes care of most of the JVM microbenchmarking issues. Here it is:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis

const val PROBLEM_SIZE = 1_000_000L

fun quickSort(array: IntArray, lo: Int, hi: Int) {
    if (lo >= hi) {
        return
    }
    val p = partition(array, lo, hi)
    quickSort(array, lo, p)
    quickSort(array, p + 1, hi)
}

private fun partition(array: IntArray, lo: Int, hi: Int): Int {
    val pivot = array[(lo + hi) / 2]
    var i = lo - 1
    var j = hi + 1
    while (true) {
        do {
            i++
        } while (array[i] < pivot)
        do {
            j--
        } while (array[j] > pivot)
        if (i >= j) {
            return j
        }
        array[i] = array[j].also { array[j] = array[i] }
    }
}

fun functionalQuickSort(numbers: IntArray): IntArray {
    return when {
        numbers.size <= 1 -> numbers
        else -> {
            val pivotIndex = 0
            functionalQuickSort(numbers.filter { it < numbers[pivotIndex] }.toIntArray()) +
                    numbers[pivotIndex] +
                    functionalQuickSort(numbers.filter { it > numbers[pivotIndex] }.toIntArray()
                    )
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    benchmark("imperative", ::runImperativeQuickSort)
    benchmark("functional", ::functionalQuickSort)
}

fun benchmark(name: String, block : (IntArray) -> IntArray) {
    println("Warming up $name")
    (1..4).forEach {
        validate(block(randomInts()))
    }
    println("Measuring")
    val average = (1..10).map {
        var result: IntArray? = null
        val input = randomInts()
        val took = measureTimeMillis {
            result = block(input)
        }
        validate(result!!)
        took
    }.average()
    println("An average $name run took $average ms")
}

private fun runImperativeQuickSort(array: IntArray): IntArray {
    quickSort(array, 0, array.size - 1)
    return array
}

private fun randomInts() = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(PROBLEM_SIZE).toArray()

private fun validate(array: IntArray) {
    var prev = array[0]
    (1 until array.size).forEach {
        array[it].also { curr ->
            require(curr >= prev)
            prev = curr
        }
    }
}
```

Typical output:

```
Warming up imperative
Measuring
An average imperative run took 106.6 ms
Warming up functional
Measuring
An average functional run took 537.4 ms
```

So... no, the functional version isn't faster.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My partitioning scheme isn't very efficient. I'm following along a lecture series, the next lecture is to implement randomization in figuring out the pivot